# ZeroDivisionError when trying to import molecule with double bonds from pdb file

Tags: import, error, vector

I'm getting an error specifically when I'm trying to import CO2 with double bonds. I tried several other molecules like benzene and there this issue doesn't seem to appear at all.

I first used Avogadro and also Molview to create the molecule and saved it as .mol.
With OpenBabel I tried to convert it to .pdb with the "generate 3D coordinates" enabled as I did for the other molecules. When importing the .pdb into blender, I had the stick option enabled. This worked for the other molecules as well.

However, the same error (see below) keeps on appearing for CO2.

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.5\3.5\scripts\addons\io_mesh_atomic\pdb_gui.py", line 198, in execute
    import_pdb(self.ball,
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.5\3.5\scripts\addons\io_mesh_atomic\pdb_import.py", line 1377, in import_pdb
    all_sticks = read_pdb_file_sticks(filepath_pdb,
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.5\3.5\scripts\addons\io_mesh_atomic\pdb_import.py", line 427, in read_pdb_file_sticks
    dist_n = dist_n / dist_n.length
ZeroDivisionError: Vector division: divide by zero error
```

This is the output from OpenBabel I'm getting

```
COMPND    UNNAMED
AUTHOR    GENERATED BY OPEN BABEL 3.1.1
HETATM    1  O   UNL     1       1.004   0.006   0.071  1.00  0.00           O  
HETATM    2  O   UNL     1       3.398   0.006   0.071  1.00  0.00           O  
HETATM    3  C   UNL     1       2.201   0.006   0.071  1.00  0.00           C  
CONECT    1    3    3                                                 
CONECT    2    3    3                                                 
CONECT    3    1    1    2    2                                       
MASTER        0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    3    0    3    0
END
```

I changed the "Stick/bonds" type from dupliverts to normal and skin but nothing worked so far

Comment: That appears to be an error in a third-party addon or program so is off-topic here. - This is a Q&A site run by volunteers to help with problems running Blender and its built-in addons **only**. Suggest you ask elsewhere.

Comment: @JohnEason io_mesh_atomic is indeed a builtin addon. see https://github.com/blender/blender-addons/tree/main/io_mesh_atomic But bugs should be reported to the official bug tracker. Go to Help > Report a bug in the header of the interface in Blender

Comment: @Gorgious Ah ok. I didn't realise that. I was confused by all the talk about external programs in the question. There's also a bug report button in the Preferences > Addons entry for that addon.